# How can I change the order Google Pinyin displays characters in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, google, chinese, fcitx, pinyin

I have a small problem. I am using Google Pinyin via Fctix on Xubuntu, and I am typing the word "彼得" a lot. However, there is a more common Chinese combination, "比的", which appears *before* the characters "彼得".

[image: screenshot]

I would rather have 彼得 appear *after* the combination 比的. Normally, Google Pinyin will automatically detect which characters you use the most, and move the most used characters to the front. But I've been typing 彼得 for a long time and it is still in "second place". Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an alternative to Google Pinyin, and that is [Sun Pinyin](https://github.com/sunpinyin/sunpinyin). In Linux, it looks exactly like Google Pinyin, but it seems to have a better memory than Google Pinyin. You can install Sun Pinyin using the following command:

- `sudo apt-get install ibus-sunpinyin sunpinyin-data`